# Javascript vanilla ajax turn response into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I am trying to experiment with javascript on a deeper level. I am building my own `$http` object that has its own `http` methods.

```
var $http = {

    get: function(url, success, error) {
        httpHelper('GET', url, success, error);
    }

};

function httpHelper(type, url, success, error) {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                success(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                error(xmlhttp.status);
            }
            else {
                error(xmlhttp.status);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open(type, url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

On the server I am returning an array of JSON objects with the request.

```
app.get('/api/players/', function(req, res) {
  res.json([
    { name: 'Mike', points: 33 }, 
    { name: 'Shaq', points: 16 }
  ]);
});
```

On the client it seems I am getting a string `[{"name":"Mike","points":33},{"name":"Shaq","points":16}]`.

How can I effectively convert the client side response to an array of JSON objects?

Comment: the response you're getting is JSON - you need to convert it to a **javascript** object using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Ok duh, everything else checks out?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the validity of the `xmlhttprequest` stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse`

```
JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though a comment has already answered the question, I felt I may as well throw out an actual answer (plus clarification on where to put it!)

You're looking for [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Where you put it depends on if your `$http` object will only be getting JSON responses or not. If it does, then put your `JSON.parse` in what you send to `success`:

```
success(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
```

However, if you also want to accept other types of requests, then put your JSON.parse in your callback that is success.

```
$http.get('some url', function(result) {
    result = JSON.parse(result);
}, function() {
    // ...
});
```